# Spark: writing BZip2 compressed parquet files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am wanting to write parquet files from a DataFrame in spark-sql with BZip2 codec compression so that they are splittable. With the following code, I'm able to use codecs such as snappy and gzip:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "snappy")
sqlContext.read.parquet(stagingDir)
        .dropDuplicates()
        .write
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .parquet(outputDir)
```

However, when I try BZip2 it seems it isn't available as I get this exception, even though I was able to write BZip2 compressed text files from an RDD

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value of spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec should be one of uncompressed, snappy, gzip, lzo, but was bzip2
```

Is there a way to write BZip2 compressed parquet files from Spark SQL?

Comment: A bzip2 compressed file wouldn't be splittable. BZip2 starts with a [Burrows-Wheeler Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform), to uncompress it you need the entire file. The error is telling you that you can't use bzip2 (and it also tells you which compressors you **can** use).

Comment: It seems it can be splittable but your comment is very interesting, thanks: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4012. I was considering lzo as it's splittable, but involves the extra step of indexing the files